# ENOENT error when building Electron app for macOS: HTML template not found in build destination

Tags: html, node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder

## This is a problem when building Electron apps.

When I develop a local app in Electron and build it, the HTML that serves as the template is not found at the build destination.

---

#### ideal state

Moving `src/html` to `build/Markdown_Viewer/mac-arm64/Markdown Viewer.app/Contents/MacOS` at build time

---

platform macOS Ventura Version 13.3.1

---

#### command

At root directory

```
sh script/build.sh
```

#### error message

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/XXX/XXX/build/Markdown_Viewer/mac-arm64/Markdown Viewer.app/Contents/MacOS/html/index.html'
```

##### build script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

> omission (of middle part of a text)

# Install dependencies
cd "$PROJECT_DIR"
echo "Now is in $(pwd)"
npm install

# Build the project
build_command=$(cat <<EOF
npx electron-builder \
    build \
    --config electron-builder.json \
    --$PLATFORM
EOF
)

eval "$build_command"

# End of Script
```

---

##### `electron-builder.json`

```json
{
    "appId": "com.example.myapp",
    "productName": "Markdown Viewer",
    "directories": {
        "output": "../build/Markdown_Viewer"
    },
    "files": [
        "index.js",
        "package.json",
        "modules/**/*",
        "html/**/*"
    ]
}
```

##### directory structure

```
❯ tree -L 2
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── build
│   └── Markdown_Viewer
├── script
│   └── build.sh
└── src
    ├── __test__
    ├── electron-builder.json
    ├── html
    ├── index.js
    ├── modules
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package-lock.json
    └── package.json

9 directories, 7 files
```

---

##### Caller of index.html

```
function handleInsertHTML( html )
{
    const currentDir = app.isPackaged ? path.dirname( process.execPath ) : path.resolve( __dirname );
    const templatePath = currentDir + '/html/index.html';
    const outputPath = currentDir + '/html/output.html';

    try
    {
        return insertHTML(
            html,
            templatePath,
            outputPath
        );
    }
    catch( error )
    {
        dialog.showErrorBox(
            "In insertHTML()",
            error.message
        );
    }
}
```

##### InsertHTML.js

```js
// Desc: Insert html string to template html

const fs = require( 'fs' );

function insertHTML( html, templatePath, outputPath )
{
    const template = fs.readFileSync( templatePath, 'utf8' );

    const pages = html.split(
        '<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>'
    );

    const pagesHTML = pages.map( ( page ) =>
    {
        return `<div class="page">${page}</div>\n`;
    }).join( '' );

    // insert html into template
    const newHTML = template.replace(
        '<!-- HTML -->',
        pagesHTML
    );

    // write new html to file
    fs.writeFileSync( outputPath, newHTML );

    return outputPath;
}


module.exports = { insertHTML };



// End of script
```

---

I'm sorry if my English is poor.

### What we tried

1. Edit electron-builder.json

use { "from": *, "to": * }

```json
    "files": [
        "index.js",
        "package.json",
        "modules/**/*",
        "html/**/*"
    ]
```

2. Change build.sh

not use `--config electron-builder.json \`

```bash
build_command=$(cat <<EOF
npx electron-builder \
    build \
    --$PLATFORM
EOF
```